# how to explain this decision tree interpretability question?

Tags: decision-tree

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgkxG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt9NA.png)

The 2 pictures above shown the 2 decision tree....

Question is: It is often claimed that a strength of decision trees is their interpretability.
Is this always justified? Refer to Figures 5 and 6 to help with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the point of the question is saying that a decision tree is interpretable if its depth is relatively small. The second tree is very deep i.e for one single prediction, you will get a high number of different splitting decisions to process. Therefore, you lose interpretability because the explanation for any prediction is an intersection of too many conditions for a human-user to process.